# VueJS Add QR to jsPDF

Tags: vue.js, qr-code, jspdf

I have the next code . how add QRcode image in my PDF

```
methods: {
download() {
  const doc = new jsPDF();

  doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
  doc.addImage("examples/images/Octonyan.jpg", "JPEG", 15, 40, 180, 180);
  // name
  doc.save("a4.pdf");
},
```

},

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF is Client-side JavaScript PDF generation, this means the image needs to be transfered as an embeded `var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...imagedata ...`

```
var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,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'
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Hello World!");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
```

jsPDF does its job well, however, there can be disadvantages, imgData should idealy be duplicated inline and thus rendered as a visible image, rather than just simply rendered for PDF inclusion, thus try to avoid either of these approaches.

The demos can be seen at http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

[image]

A similar Demo set can be seen at https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

[image]